# how to display image in full screen on clicked in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to display the loaded image in new activity, which the name is fullscreenActivity but it can't. can any one help me to find out this solution.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:padding="0dp"/>



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView, fullimage;
    private Context context;
    private Uri uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        fullimage = findViewById(R.id.fulscreenimage);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullscreenimageActivity.class));

                Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(fullimage);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `layout_height="200dp"` - This means your image wont be any taller than 200dp.

Comment: yes I know that but I want to show the image in new activity, which the name is fullscreen activity. On that image click I want to show that image in full screen....in new activity

Answer (score 0):

*Just open an another activity by PutIntent. Full screnn activity set a imageview set it match parents and set scale type*